# Problems making a spell checker, I cant remove the Punctuation

Tags: c, spell-checking, punctuation

Spell-Checker:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "search.h"

int main(void)
{   
    FILE *f = fopen("mistakes.txt", "w");
    FILE *fPointer;
    FILE *dictionary;
    //int a,b;
    char fname[20];
    char wordcheck[45];
    char worddict[45];

    char dummy;
    int i;
    int notfound;
    int k;
```

> This is the files i am using including the dictionary file that has the words 
>   i compare to the other text file

```
    ///^below add text file to be read
    fPointer = fopen("fname", "r");
    dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt","r");
```

---

```
if (f == NULL)
       {
        printf("Error oping file!\n");
        exit(1);
       }
```

---

*I have created this loop to make the words lower cased and identify the punctuation*

```
    while(fscanf(fPointer,"%s", wordcheck)!=EOF)// makes all characters lower case
    {      // an array that contains the characters of the original word
        char wordChars[1000];

        int newwordlength = 0;
            // loops through each character in a word
        for (i=0; i < strlen(wordcheck); i++)
         {
            // makes all words lower cased
            wordcheck[i] = tolower(wordcheck[i]);
            // checks the word has these characters and increments newwordlength where the character is a letter
              if (wordChars[i] != ',' 
              && wordChars[i] != '.' 
              && wordChars[i] != '?' 
              && wordChars[i] != '!' 
              && wordChars[i] != ':')
            {    // how long the word will be without these characters
                newwordlength++;
            }           
         } 
        //  creates new character array with size newwordlength
        char newWordChars[1000];
            *I think my problem is in this part*
        int currChar = 0;
  **This is where i think my problem is as its not removing the the characters **
        // loops through these characters and only adds non-punctuation characters to the new character array
        for (k = 0; k < strlen(wordChars); k++)
        {
            if (wordChars[k] != ','
                && wordChars[k] != '.'
                && wordChars[k] != '?'
                && wordChars[k] != '!'
                && wordChars[k] != ':')
              {
                newWordChars[currChar] = wordChars[k];
                currChar++;
              }
        }
```

When I use this loop, I copy the mistakes into a text file but it copies the punctuation as well

---

```
        fseek(dictionary,0,SEEK_SET);

    while(fscanf(dictionary,"%s", worddict)!=EOF)
      {
        notfound = 1;
        if(strcmp(wordcheck, worddict)==0)// compares strings//
            {
              printf("This word: %s is in the dictionary\n", wordcheck);
              notfound = 0;

               break;
            }
      }
    if(notfound == 1)
```

> This is where it copies the txt file.

```
      {
        printf("%s is not in the dictionary\n", wordcheck);
        const char *mistakes = "Write this to file";
        fprintf(f, "Words not in the dictionary: %s\n", wordcheck);
      }
    printf("Your file has been checked. Please check your errors by typing mistakes.txt to view ");
    }

    fclose(dictionary);
    fclose(fPointer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a comment saying "makes all characters lower case", but there is no code actually doing it.

Comment: You might also want to read about the [`ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/ispunct) function.

Comment: Can you please explain why you leave so many useless blank lines? Because I would love to hear a reason for that.

Comment: Lastly, you should learn how to use a debugger. With a debugger you can step through the code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their value. It should hopefully help you understand what goes wrong, and where.

Comment: If you are spell checking then you need to check letters only, anything else  can be removed with `!isalpha()`.

Comment: Creating a [MCVE] may help here too.

Comment: One last *last* thing. There seems to be a lot of code missing between the snippets. Are you sure you only show the relevant parts? That you don't leave out some important part? Can't you show less (but more relevant) code?

Comment: "Too many blank lines" - said my good ol' friend PEP-8

Comment: The `ispunct()` function may be helpful. Though overall, I think you only want to focus on letters and spaces, and discard everything else.